# How to remove or reset all metadata from FileGeoDatabase (*.gdb)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, metadata

Removing metadata from shapefiles is fairly easy, since they are stored in a seperate xml file.

How can I remove or reset all metadata in a FileGeoDatabase (*.gdb)?

Comment: The only way to corrupt metadata like that would be to create a new feature class with the same field names/types, copy the rows, drop the original, and rename the clone.

Comment: I am assuming you mean the geoprocessing history? There is a tool for that:    arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management(). If I am wrong, I guess you could always import a blank metadata file using import http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/import-metadata.htm

Comment: Sadly arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management() only works with SDE not with *.gdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks and 1up for your idea, Ben S Nadler. Using the following function to import an blank metadata file does the trick for me.

> arcpy.ImportMetadata_conversion()

Comment: Has anyone tried this method on a large dataset? I have a FGDB with 400+ layers (vector and raster) and was curious if anyone else experienced any problems replacing all the metadata with a blank metadata file. Some odd reason it kills ArcCatalog for me. I am simply trying to remove all the metadata from the FGDB. I miss using the simpler Personal GeoDatabase (PGDB) as you could remove all the metadata with a couple of clicks going through the MS Access tables (back end).